# ni compile error under diamondback

Tags: rosmake, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I install the latest diamondback (RC3) and trying to install ni per http://www.ros.org/wiki/ni
However, on step "rosmake ni --rosdep-install", I got the following error for the "disparity_view". it seems to look for the cturtle link in the diamondback ni build.
Can someone fix this?
thanks,
-Qi

Output below:

```
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> disparity_view [ make ]                                                                                                           
[ rosmake ] All 16 linesisparity_view: 0.7 sec ]                                                                                [ 1 Active 28/63 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  CMake Error at build/CMakeFiles/CMakeSystem.cmake:1 (INCLUDE):
    include could not find load file:
  
      /opt/ros/cturtle/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
      
  [rosbuild] Building package disparity_view
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package disparity_view written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/blurpc2/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110227-152728/disparity_view/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< disparity_view [FAIL] [ 0.73 seconds ]                                                                                            
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package disparity_view.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9223/ni-compile-error-under-diamondback/) by [Qi](https://answers.ros.org/users/193/qi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2011-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK. I have finally successfully compiled the ni with the following changes:

1. in  ~/ni/setup.sh, change cturtle to damondback.
2. in the following files, change cturtle to damondback.
   /home/blurpc2/ni/ni/pointcloud_to_laserscan/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeSystem.cmake
   /home/blurpc2/ni/ni/openni_tracker/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeSystem.cmake
   /home/blurpc2/ni/ni/disparity_view/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeSystem.cmake

After the above changes, ni compiles under diamondback! ;)

---

Originally posted by [Qi](https://answers.ros.org/users/193/qi/) with karma: 28 on 2011-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-02-28**:
I imagine the 'recommended' way to do #1 would be to re-run rosinstall, though personally, I would just add ~/ni to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in .bashrc and not bother with rosinstall. But for #2 you shouldn't have to change those files as they are autogenerated. The --pre-clean flag for rosmake would help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Something is wrong with your diamondback install if cturtle is being mentioned in the rosmake output. Are you sure you followed the diamondback install instructions for ni? Did you previously have cturtle on your system?

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-02-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-02-27**:
Even if all the ros-cturtle-* packages were still installed on your system, that wouldn't matter, unless they are somehow being pointed to. That could be happening if you still have something leftover in your .bashrc, or perhaps due to the arguments you gave to rosinstall when you installed ni.

**Comment by [Qi](https://answers.ros.org/users/193/qi/) on 2011-02-27**:
I had installed cturtle before for kinect. it is deprecated by ROS now. so I removed it by "sudo apt-get purge ros-cturtle* ". Did i missed anything else to wipe cturtle out?